# where do I put bootstrap fonts folder in Rails for production?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, heroku

I have the bootstrap 3 files residing in my vendor/assets/stylesheets folder. Within there I also have the BS folder "fonts". I can re-write the styles in bootstrap.css to point to that folder in dev, but where and how do I do this in production (Heroku). Currently my images (e.g. glyphicons) are not showing. Any help much appreciated.

Bizt

Comment: what html you are putting for showing  glyphicons. you use bootstrap through a Gem right?

Comment: why you are putting them in vendor. use gem for bootstrap 3

Answer (score 1):

You should put your `fonts` folder inside of `rails_app/public` directory.